# Fujifilm ASK2000 - how to print from Linux

Tags: printing, drivers, ubuntu-14.04

My company have Fujifilm ASK 2000 photo printer. I can't find any drivers for Linux.

Maybe anybody know is it possible to use it with Linux? 
Maybe the printer uses some standard printer language like PCL or PostScript?

Linux Distribution is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Since this sounds like an industrial printer (the manual mentions that it takes two people to lift it), I would suggest you ask the vendor.

Comment: The USB Vendor ID does not appear to be registered. This would make Linux support a tad difficult (since there may not be a USB driver available). See my updated answer for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** This printer does not work "out-of-the-box" with Ubuntu 14.04.

**Additional Details:**

**EDIT:** HopelessN00B pointed-out there's OSX drivers available. Though OSX is closer to BSD than Linux (as others have mentioned), there may be a chance;

The OSX driver download contains [two *.dmg files](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1155734). If there's a PPD file or two in there, [there's a chance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59845/can-cups-ppd-files-for-mac-os-x-be-used-for-linux) they could be used.

The [manual](http://www.fujifilmusa.com/shared/bin/ASK2000InstructionManual060420.pdf) mentions USB 2.0 support. Plug-in a Linux system and review the output from "`lsusb`".
From there, you should be able to determine if there's a driver available.

**EDIT:** Since the addition of the `lsusb` output, we can check the [Linux USB ID Database](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb-ids.html)

```
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 07ce:c009
```

Interpreting the [USB ID](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB) is the easy part;

- First four hex digits are the "Vendor ID" (`07ce:`)
- Second four hex digits are the "Product ID" (`:c009`)

Unfortunately, the USB ID DB doesn't yield any hits;

**USB ID DB Entries**

```
07cd    Elektor
07cf    Casio Computer Co., Ltd
```

It goes from 07c**d** to 07c**f** (skipping 07c**e** entirely).
I would suspect that the product has been second-sourced (made by someone else on FujiFilm's behalf), according to the [USB-IF FAQ](http://www.usb.org/developers/usbfaq#12)

Your Linux distribution of choice may have a "printer setup wizard" that you may want to try.

Comment: Bus 003 Device 007: ID 07ce:c009

Comment: The wizard can't find anything (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 so it's quite up to date).
Maybe some output from windows can help? Maybe there is some Win utility I can use to provide you with some useful information?

Comment: I have looked-up hardware using the Windows "Device Manager" to help in googling for drivers & advice. Give it a shot.
Note the name of the device ("Friendly Name" in the Details/Properties pane), the "Manufacturer", the Driver used and the version number.

Answer (score 2):

[They don't seem to offer Linux drivers on their website, but they do offer OSX drivers](http://www.fujifilmusa.com/support/ServiceSupportProduct.do?prodcat=864218).  Since [OSX is really just a customized version of <s>Linux</s> BSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeXTSTEP), you might be able to make the OSX drivers work on Linux, with a little effort.

The linked page also has a contact option - I'd ask Fuji about their Linux support before doing anything else, as that seems like the easiest, lowest effort approach.

Comment: The contact form and help system is kind of loop - you always end in the same place with no answer. There is no contact form or email address provided... You only can call them... Which I'll try but don't expect much...

Comment: @Kornel Please let us know what you hear from the vendor. Also, see if you can get the output from `lsusb` for the device. If you don't have a Linux system handy, there's many "Live-Boot Linux CD" images out there (`ubuntu`, `knoppix`, etc)

Comment: @Kornel Yeah, I wouldn't hold my breath either... [but I do like signal15's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/653724/118258).  I'd probably try that right after not holding my breath to hear back from Fuji.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I'm a hardware-junkie at heart, so anything new gets me excited. Haven't personally "played" with many industrial photo printers before.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5606 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 07ce:c009  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Bus 003 Device 007: ID 07ce:c009

Comment: This empty if from the printer. Not very talkative

Comment: @Kornel You should post those as comments to Signal15's answer, if you want him to get notified, and increase the chances of him seeing them.

Comment: OSX is based on freebsd, and not on linux. The drivers are binary incompatible. :-( (Although the difference is smaller as between linux and win were)

Comment: The OSX drivers on FujiFilm's website have two *.dmg files in them. **IF** there's a PPD file in there somewhere, maybe there's a chance;

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59845/can-cups-ppd-files-for-mac-os-x-be-used-for-linux

Comment: I was on short vacations. I'll try to play with Mac's PPDs and let you know. So far I was unable to contact FujiFilm (but honestly I didn't try too hard so far).